# Get a blank sign in Twig Template for generating a PDF with PHPBundle

Tags: php, symfony, pdf

I want a required blank in the twig template of PHPPdf PDFBundle in Symfony2. But the HTML Tag `&nbsp;` don't work here. For example I want a simple table with a blank in each cell:

```
 <pdf>
    <dynamic-page>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Line 1</td>
            <td>Line 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>In next cell the blank</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </dynamic-page>
 </pdf>
```

But how I write before, the code `&nbsp;` is not allowed from the template. How can I get it on another way. And only to write a blank is not possible for each situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. It works when I use the unicode for a blank `&#32;`

```
<pdf>
  <dynamic-page>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Line 1</td>
        <td>Line 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>In next cell the blank</td>
        <td>&#32;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
 </dynamic-page>
</pdf>
```